# Any details from http://ui-grid.info is not loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

We have UI-Grid components loaded from http://ui-grid.info like below :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css"></link>
        <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>

        <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
```

And all these are failing to load today as of 18-May-2016, Is this site down ??

How can i get all these files back again as we are not supposed to have downtime for our apps.

Also is it suggested to load these files locally and have a reference for the same ??

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah looks like it is down, the Domain name has been canceled.
When you link to external libraries you are always at the mercy of the publishers, they could decide to block remote linking whenever they want to or close the site down.

Anyways your source files luckily still available on GIT: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid

Answer (score 0):

Me too waiting to see something on it's documentation:

BTW, to your problem , replace those broken urls with followings:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/3.1.1/ui-grid.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/3.1.1/ui-grid.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.11/ng-grid-csv-export.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.20/pdfmake.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.20/vfs_fonts.js
```

I am not sure about `ng-grid-csv-export.js` but others should be OK.